# _mm_sad_epu8 faster than _mm_sad_pu8

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics

In a benchmark test, the 128-bit intrinsic function performs faster than the 64-bit intrinsic?

```
_mm_sad_epu8(__m128i, __m128i) //Clocks: 0.0300
_mm_sad_pu8(__m64, __m64)      //Clocks: 0.0491
```

From what I understand, The Intel Reference Manual, states that `(PSADBW)` has a latency of 5 and throughput of 1 on mmx registers, but does not state performance for mm registers.

Should they not be equally fast, and is this general for intrinsic functions taking 128-bit arguments?

Comment: How did you measure the execution time?

Comment: clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Comment: Ok, then: Does the benchmark loop runs for several seconds? Does the processor reaches the same turbo frequency? And which processor is it actually?

Comment: I have tried different loop iterations up to several seconds. I have also tried reordering the statements, so that potential turbo CPU-features should be eliminated.

Comment: Could you please link the mentionded _Intel Reference Manual_. I have looked up this [Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf) as well as this [Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_sad&expand=4515). None of them defines the timing when using MM registers.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I must have misread the Instruction Set Reference. I have edited my quedtion. I still find it odd that it is slower on mm registers.

Comment: You still haven't posted what CPU you have.  [Agner Fog's](http://agner.org/optimize/) show Intel SnB having a latency of 5c for it, with a throughput of 1/c.  The entry says `psadbw (x)mm, (x)mm`, meaning that the data is the same for the xmm and mm forms.  If you're just timing the whole function, the mmx version will have probably an extra `emms` in your loop somewhere, causing a small amount of overhead.  It's 31 uops on SnB, and takes several cycles to complete.  (throughput is one per 18c, but IDK how much it delays other instructions.)  I assume you're using `-O3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My measurement program (see below) reveals that on a Core-i5 3450 (Ivy Bridge) the performance of `_mm_sad_epu8` equals that of `_mm_sad_pu8`. The latter is even slightly faster.

The output of my program is:

```
warmup:              1.918 sec total
measure_mm_sad_epu8: 1.904 sec total, 0.372 nsec per operation
measure_mm_sad_pu8:  1.872 sec total, 0.366 nsec per operation
```

The turbo clock frequency of my processor is 3.5 GHz (single thread), and the throughput of `_mm_sad_epu8` should be 1 clock cycle according to the [Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_sad&expand=4512). Thus, each operation should take at least 0.286 nsec. So my measurement program reached about 77% of the max performance.

I used Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express and created a new Win32 console application. The program has been compiled with the standard "Release" settings. This is the code of the cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

extern "C" {
  #include <emmintrin.h>
}

float measure_mm_sad_epu8(int n, int repeat) {
    assert(n % 16 == 0);
    // Didn't get an aligned "new" to work :-(
    __m128i *input  = (__m128i *) _aligned_malloc(n * sizeof *input,  16);
    __m128i *output = (__m128i *) _aligned_malloc(n * sizeof *output, 16);
    if(!input || !output) exit(1);
    __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
        input[i].m128i_i64[0] = 0x0123456789abcdef;
        input[i].m128i_i64[1] = 0xfedcba9876543210;
    }

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    for(int r = 0; r < repeat; r++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=16) { // loop unrolled
            output[i  ] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i  ], zero);
            output[i+1] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+1], zero);
            output[i+2] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+2], zero);
            output[i+3] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+3], zero);
            output[i+4] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+4], zero);
            output[i+5] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+5], zero);
            output[i+6] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+6], zero);
            output[i+7] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+7], zero);
            output[i+8] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+8], zero);
            output[i+9] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+9], zero);
            output[i+10] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+10], zero);
            output[i+11] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+11], zero);
            output[i+12] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+12], zero);
            output[i+13] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+13], zero);
            output[i+14] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+14], zero);
            output[i+15] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i+15], zero);
        }
    }
    _mm_empty();
    clock_t endTime = clock();

    _aligned_free(input);
    _aligned_free(output);
    return (endTime-startTime)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

float measure_mm_sad_pu8(int n, int repeat) {
    assert(n % 16 == 0);
    // Didn't get an aligned "new" to work :-(
    __m64 *input  = (__m64 *) _aligned_malloc(n * sizeof *input,  16);
    __m64 *output = (__m64 *) _aligned_malloc(n * sizeof *output, 16);
    if(!input || !output) exit(1);
    __m64 zero = _mm_setzero_si64();

    for(int i=0; i < n; i+=2) {
        input[i  ].m64_i64 = 0x0123456789abcdef;
        input[i+1].m64_i64 = 0xfedcba9876543210;
    }

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    for(int r = 0; r < repeat; r++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i+=16) { // loop unrolled
            output[i  ] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i  ], zero);
            output[i+1] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+1], zero);
            output[i+2] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+2], zero);
            output[i+3] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+3], zero);
            output[i+4] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+4], zero);
            output[i+5] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+5], zero);
            output[i+6] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+6], zero);
            output[i+6] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+7], zero);
            output[i+7] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+8], zero);
            output[i+8] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+9], zero);
            output[i+10] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+10], zero);
            output[i+11] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+11], zero);
            output[i+12] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+12], zero);
            output[i+13] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+13], zero);
            output[i+14] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+14], zero);
            output[i+15] = _mm_sad_pu8(input[i+15], zero);
        }
    }
    _mm_empty();
    clock_t endTime = clock();

    _aligned_free(input);
    _aligned_free(output);
    return (endTime-startTime)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int n = 256, repeat = 20000000;
    float time;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed;

    time = measure_mm_sad_epu8(n,repeat);
    std::cout << "warmup:              " << time << " sec total" << std::endl;
    time = measure_mm_sad_epu8(n,repeat);
    std::cout << "measure_mm_sad_epu8: " << time << " sec total, " << time/n/repeat*1e9 << " nsec per operation" << std::endl;

    n*=2;      // same memory footprint
    repeat/=2; // but with same amount of calculations
    time = measure_mm_sad_pu8(n,repeat);
    std::cout << "measure_mm_sad_pu8:  " << time << " sec total, " << time/n/repeat*1e9 << " nsec per operation" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the unmodified "stdafx.h":

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

**EDIT**: For each operation `output[i] = _mm_sad_epu8(input[i], zero);`
in the unrolled loop, the compiler generates a vector load, a `psadbw` and a vector store like this (just with differing pointer arithmetic):

```
013410D0  movdqa      xmm1,xmmword ptr [ecx-30h]  
013410D5  psadbw      xmm1,xmm0  
013410D9  movdqa      xmmword ptr [eax-10h],xmm1  

013410DE  ...
```

The IvyBridge has enough (pipeline) ports to execute this at the "same" time.
The generated code only uses the `xmm1` and `xmm0` register, thus it relies on the register renaming of the processor. **EDIT2**: Due to the changing address arithmetic, the code length varies from 13 to 20 bytes. Thus, the code may suffer from a decoder bottleneck because Ivy Bridge can only decode 16 bytes per clock cycle (and max 4 instructions). On the other hand, it has a loop cache to handle this.

The generated code for the MMX version is almost the same:

```
013412D4  movq        mm1,mmword ptr [ecx-18h]  
013412D8  psadbw      mm1,mm0  
013412DB  movq        mmword ptr [eax-8],mm1  

013412DF  ...
```

The memory footprint is 2*4 KiB for both versions, because I doubled the number of elements in the MMX version (see main).

Comment: Thanks for the extensive work. This code is more or less equal to the benchmark program i created. I however compiled in Xcode and it may results from different compile settings.

Comment: That doesn't *quite* all fit in registers, so there's a load and store for every `psadbw`.  Writing it as `_mm_sad_epu8(zero, input[i+1]);` (args in the other order) does convince [gcc to fold the load into a memory argument](http://goo.gl/bpTuZ8) like clang does always (when targeting AVX, where 3-operand non-destructive operation allows that to work without clobbering the zeroed vector reg.)  Anyway, this probably still saturates port0 on your IvB with psadbw.  Maybe smaller cache footprint of the MMX version makes the tiny diff: fewer cache-lines to refill if evicted?

Comment: @PeterCordes I have added some more details about the generated code to my answer. The cache footprint is the same for both versions because I doubled the number of elements in the MMX version (see main). Folding did not work with my compiler. You have used a 64-bit compiler. I have only a 32-bit compiler here at the moment. :-(

Comment: Oh, I see, you're actually looping over a larger buffer.  I was expecting the code to just loop over an array of 16 elements or something, assuming you were hoping to have it emit a loop of *just* `psadbw` instructions, without any loads/stores that could be a bottleneck.  So I didn't read carefully enough to see that's not what you were doing at all!